# Datatable overflow (item not show completely)

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a datatable and this select inside one row:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-success" >
    <option>Completed</option>
    <option>In progress</option>
    <option>Overdue</option>
</select>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$('#my-table').dataTable({
    'iDisplayLength': 10
});

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

And the problem is that the select is cut when it gets out of the table:
[image: Screenshot]

How can i fix this?

Comment: can i know which bootstrap version you are using. so that i can help to solve this issue

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3.7